# Locate line in asp.net dataview

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an asp.net page with a dataview loading records from an sql database. It works fine. No problems. I want to automatically highlight a specific record when an server side event is received with the ID of the record to highlight.

The code I've tried works if I manually set a variable to the record ID (see example). The PROBLEM IS that when I try to use the row to locate ID received from the SSE, it does not work. I expect it may be a syntax error in my code that searches for the text in the line.

```
/*  ********************************************************************
    EXAMPLE 1. THIS WORKS
    ********************************************************************    */
if (typeof (EventSource) !== "undefined") {
    var source = new EventSource("/dataPush/dataOrderPush.php");
    var findThisLine = "row_112.00";
    
    $('#ListView1_cmrUL li:contains("' + findThisLine + '")').scrollintoview();
    $('#ListView1_cmrUL li').removeClass('active');
    $('#ListView1_cmrUL li:contains("' + findThisLine + '")').addClass('active');
                                            
                                        
/*  ********************************************************************
    EXAMPLE 2. This does NOT WORK
    Manually setting variable to data returned from server side event.
    This does NOT WORK even though the event.data is the same text as 
    set manually in example 1.
    ********************************************************************    */  
if (typeof (EventSource) !== "undefined") {
    var source = new EventSource("/dataPush/dataOrderPush.php");
    var findThisLine = event.data;
    
    $('#ListView1_cmrUL li:contains("' + findThisLine + '")').scrollintoview();
    $('#ListView1_cmrUL li').removeClass('active');
    $('#ListView1_cmrUL li:contains("' + findThisLine + '")').addClass('active');
    
    
/*  ********************************************************************
    EXAMPLE 3. This does NOT WORK
    This attempts to use the data returned from the SSE directly
    ********************************************************************    */                      
if (typeof (EventSource) !== "undefined") {
    var source = new EventSource("/dataPush/dataOrderPush.php");
    
    $('#ListView1_cmrUL li:contains("' + event.data + '")').scrollintoview();
    $('#ListView1_cmrUL li').removeClass('active');
    $('#ListView1_cmrUL li:contains("' + event.data + '")').addClass('active');
```

Here's more information about the event. It is a *server side event* that echoes the content of a text file. I'll show both.

This is the server side event php. It echoes the content of a text file.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

$metaOrderInfo = file_get_contents("playOrder.txt");
echo "data: $metaOrderInfo \n\n";
?>
```

For now (testing), the content of the text file is just this:

```
row_112.00
```

This line on the client reads the stream event from the server. The code in the client is just:

```
var source = new EventSource("/dataPush/dataOrderPush.php");
```

That's how server side events work. I have verified that the returned value is that in the text file.

I send the returned event data to the console:

```
console.log(event.data);
```

And this is shown in the console. You can see that the data is received automatically every few seconds. That's the server-side event php. When in operation, the actual text in the file would change sometimes. Here, it does not change, for testing.

```
10:13:17.306 row_112.00 
10:13:22.349 row_112.00 
10:13:27.385 row_112.00 
10:13:32.418 row_112.00 
10:13:37.452 row_112.00 
10:13:42.492 row_112.00
```

In other words, the client gets the updated value automatically, and THIS PART WORKS. The event.data returned matches the data in the server text file. If I insert a console log entry for it, I can see that it is correct.

So the question is still, why the variable doesn't work with that data on the client side.

Again, I thank you for your time helping me with this. I hope this makes it clear.

Comment: so this `event.data` is return something wrong - debug it. - And the `event` is not exist on the code you have here

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do you mean that if my variable does contain valid data then the syntax I use should work?  I didn't post the event (php on the server) because this works and returns text data.

Comment: look, the `event` is not defined anywhere here... and the `source` also not used here - your code actually is a part that not make sense for get any help.

Comment: I've updated the question to show the information your asking for, so I would really appreciate your taking another look at it for me. Thanks.